# selecting columns from all tables in a mysql database

Tags: mysql

I want to select 2 columns from all the tables in database

```
select status, up_down_time
from all_tables
ORDER BY ID DESC LIMIT 1`
```

also I wondering if I can use `show tables`

Comment: I want to store store all tables in a variables

Comment: you can use a prepared statement where you select all tables SELECT table_name FROM information_schema.tables;  and build a query that you execute.